# Changing MainPage on OnResume event

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm developing a small application with Xamarin Forms, the app requires signed user so MainPage in App constructor is set to LoginPage.

After a user is signed on I'm changing MainPage to AppShell, this part runs smoothly but I need to redirect a user to LoginPage each time when an application was resumed.

My code looks like this:

App.xaml.cs

```cs
public App()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  DependencyService.Register<RestDataStore>();
  DependencyService.Register<CredentialsService>();

  MainPage = new LoginPage();
}
```

Redirect in ViewModel of LoginPage to AppShell

```cs
public void OnSubmit()
{
  ...               
  Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell(); 
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```cs
protected override void OnResume()
{
  MainPage = new LoginPage();
}
```

when i do Page changing like this, nothing will happen.

Is there any other way to change MainPage after an application was resumed?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you verified the code in OnResume is executing?  Forcing the user to login every time they task switch seems like a really bad UX design

Comment: Also why add it as a dependency service? The login shouldnt matter the platform.

Comment: Yes I did and the event is fired correctly, but Page remains the same as before suspending. Our customer requires this behavior because of company strict security measures.

Comment: instead of setting MainPage like that, just use `await Navigation.PushAsync (new LoginPage ());`

Comment: I've changed code from constructor to `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());` , the redirect to AppShell to `Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync( new AppShell());` and OnResume to `var nav = MainPage.Navigation;
   await nav.PushAsync(new LoginPage());` but the OnResume redirect doesn't work and now it is throwing exception about Navigating on Android, that I should use NavigationPage.

Comment: Not able to reproduce. It is working without issue on both platforms!

Comment: I'm not sure what was wrong, but when I recreated project one more time, then the solution provided by @VahidShir started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MasterDetailPage in you app?

if so:

```
    public static void SetDatailPage(Page page)
    {
        if (App.Current.MainPage is MasterDetailPage)
        {
            var masterPage = (MasterDetailPage)App.Current.MainPage;
            masterPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
        }
    }
```

And

```
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
        SetDatailPage(new LoginPage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
protected override async void OnResume()
{

  await MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NoConnectionPage());

}
```

The only drawback is that it will be modal.